# Sources for a used Positive Displacement pump

Tags: pump

I am making a dyno to measure gokart engine torque for a highschool project.  I would like to use a water brake by varying input/output through a water pump and have read that this should be a positive displacement (not centrifugal).  It would be great if you could provide ideas where I could find a cheap pump.  For example, could I find a suitable pump at an auto wrecker?  What car manufacturers would use a PD pump?  Thanks for any input.

Comment: Thanks for your time Mart!!  I will post where you suggested.

Comment: This is a duplicate as @Danny asked it of his own accord.